# Verification that my SSRS subscription was emailed to a valid address

Tags: ssrs

I would like to know if it is possible to verify that an SSRS subscription that was set up to send an email sent it to a real address.  That is, if I put in an email address that is not valid, can I find out that an undeliverable message was sent back from the destination server?

I tested this with an email address that does return an undeliverable message when I emailed to it from Outlook.  After the subscription ran, its status simply said `Mail sent to abc@abc.com`.

**OUR SOLUTION:** We set up a shared Outlook account with a generic email address.  Those of us who have access to create subscriptions have access to this email account.  We then modified the `RSReportServer.config` file on the ReportServer to send emails from this new generic address.  Now, any time a subscription is set up to send to an incorrect email address, we can see the delivery failure in the shared Outlook inbox.  Woo hoo!

Comment: This different but related [ServerFault anwer](http://serverfault.com/a/251896) may be of help. I'm not sure if things like NDRs even get back to reporting services, you may just have to check your mail server log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to set up a Reply email: address when you you are configuring database mail.  This will send the bounce back messages to that email account.

UPDATE:

The bounce-back for invalid email addresses will go to the FROM address.  The Reply-To address is used only by an email program when a user tries to reply to the message.  Change the FROM email address and see if you get the bounce-back your inbox.

If you get the bounce-back to the from address you can setup a mailbox to collect these messages.

Comment: I tried to set the reply-to at the subscription level and it did not appear to work.  My impression was that reply-to would override the server setting.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Please see the updated information above.  Test out the FROM address and see if you see bounce-back emails going there.

Comment: That makes sense - that it would go to the FROM.  It will take a bit more maneuvering for me to test this, but sounds promising!

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I have updated the question with my solution.